# C# how to create a custom xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I'm really just trying to create a custom xml document for simple configuration processing.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        string[] NodeArray = { "Fruits|Fruit", "Vegetables|Veggie"};
        foreach (string node in NodeArray)
        {
            XmlNode xmlNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,node.Split('|')[0],null);
            //xmlNode.Value = node.Split('|')[0];
            xmlNode.InnerText = node.Split('|')[1];
            xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode);

        }
```

What i'm trying to get is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Fruits>Fruit</Fruits>
<Vegetables>Veggie</Vegetables>
```

i get not set to value of an object at `xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode);`

Comment: The example document you posted is not a valid xml documnet. Each xml should have only one root node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't make that XML structure.

All XML documents must have a single root node.  You can't have more.

Try something like this

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

xDoc.AppendChild( xDoc.CreateElement("root"));

string[] NodeArray = { "Fruits|Fruit", "Vegetables|Veggie" };
foreach (string node in NodeArray)
{
    XmlNode xmlNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, node.Split('|')[0], null);
    //xmlNode.Value = node.Split('|')[0];
    xmlNode.InnerText = node.Split('|')[1];
    xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have that XML structure as XML MUST have a single root element. You may want to try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<items>
  <Fruits>Fruit</Fruits>
  <Vegetables>Veggie</Vegetables>
</items>
```